# no error but os.copy does not copy files

Tags: python

I know this is very basic, but I dont know how to fix it when there is no error apparently. thanks

```
import os
import shutil

# First, create a list and populate it with the files
# you want to find (1 file per row in myfiles.txt)
files_to_find = []
with open('C:/Users/me/Desktop/test/_FileList.txt') as fh:
    for row in fh:
        files_to_find.append(row.strip)

# Then we recursively traverse through each folder
# and match each file against our list of files to find.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/Users/me/Desktop/test/newfolder'):
    for _file in files:
        if _file in files_to_find:
            # If we find it, notify us about it and copy it it to C:\NewPath\
            shutil.copy(os.path.abspath(root + '/' + _file), 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/test/')
```

Comment: `row.strip` -> `row.strip()`?

Comment: If there is no error and no copy => `shutil.copy` is not being called -> `if` condition must be always `False` -> your `files_to_find` list is a list of *methods*, not strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call to `.strip()` method is missing `()`; `files_to_find` contains method reference, not filename string list.

```
>>> row = 'abc\n'
>>> row.strip
<built-in method strip of str object at 0x0000000002C5EAF8>
>>> row.strip()
'abc'
```

Replace following line:

```
files_to_find.append(row.strip)
```

with:

```
files_to_find.append(row.strip())
```

Comment: @user2708115 The contents of `_FileList.txt` do **not** match the files in the directory. This is the only guess we can make without a mwe.

Comment: @user2708115, What you get if you print `files_to_find`?

Comment: i was still getting the files_to_find array actually,

Comment: I get the filename which I can see in the folder am copying from

Comment: @user2708115, I don't understand what you mean? Could you update your question with the cotnent of `C:/Users/me/Desktop/test/_FileList.txt` file?

Comment: I am testing so i just put this filename in that list 20130613_080435.txt which i just copied from my os.walk('C:/Users/me/Desktop/test/newfolder'

Comment: @user2708115, Please show the result of `print(files_to_find)` in the question instead of explaning in the comment.

Comment: [Dbg]>>> 
['20130613_080435.txt']

Comment: I think its not going into the loop coz I am not reaching the if statement ?